# Sistema de recomendación en meteor usando easysearch

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Estoy terminando un proyecto cuyo reto final es que el sistema pueda recomendar otros sitios web en base a votar positivo a un sitio o comentar en él.

El sistema usa un campo `keywords`en el cuál se basa una búsqueda que hace uso de `easysearch`, y sobre el cuál me quiero basar para hacer ese sistema de recomendación.

El algoritmo es simple, cuando el usuario vota positivo al sitio el evento encuentra todas sus palabras claves y envía una búsqueda `easysearch` que encuentra sitios con al menos una de las palabras clave, retorna sólo un sitio aleatoriamente y devuelve el resultado en un bonito mensaje modal.

La plantilla para el mensaje es:

```
<template name="recommend_site">
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="alertdialog" id="website_recommend">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h6 class="text-right">{{momentFormat createdOn}}</h6>
                    <p>
                        {{description}}
                    </p>
                    <a href="/site/{{_id}}">See more...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <span class="badge alert-success">{{votes.Up}}</span>
                    {{#if currentUser}}
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                            <button class="btn btn-default js-upvote">
                                <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default js-downvote">
                                <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    {{/if}}
                    <span class="badge alert-danger">{{votes.Down}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

El evento que debe hacer uso de esta búsqueda es:

```
Template.website_item.events({
    "click .js-upvote": function (event) {
        var website_id = this._id;
        var keywords = this.keywords;
        console.log("Up voting website with id " + website_id);

        Websites.update({_id: website_id},
            {$inc: {'votes.Up': 1}});

        WebsitesIndex.getComponentMethods().search(keywords);

        console.log(keywords);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Y el ejemplo del documento sitio web es:

```
    Websites.insert({
        title:"Google",
        url:"http://www.google.com",
        description:"Popular search engine.",
        keywords: ['google', 'popular', 'search', 'engine'],
        votes:{
            Up: 0,
            Down: 0
        },
        createdOn:new Date()
    });
```

Como he dicho antes, la búsqueda con [easysearch](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/) funciona estupendamente, pero no logro ubicar de que manera hacer la búsqueda tomando las palabras clave y mandar el resultado a la plantilla. Como pueden ver en el evento hice un intento de obtener el resultado siguiendo la documentación, pero de ahí para allá no se me ocurre que más puedo hacer.

Alguien me puede guiar?

Answer (score 1):

Si solo necesitas UN resultado es mejor que lo hagas a través de un método algo así.

```
Websites.findOne(
/** Que contenga al menos una de las palabras clave **/
  { keywords : { $in : input_array_of_keywords } } , 
/** El que tenga mayor votación **/
  { sort : { "votes.up" : -1 } }
);
```